# whereis python3 gives several paths

Tags: python3

I am wondering if I have installed python3 "multiply" by several actions when fixing some problems.
Typing `whereis python3` in my ubuntu 18.04 gives

> python3: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Do I have to remove something?

By the way:
`python3 --version` gives

> Python 3.6.9

Edit: `dpkg -l | grep python3.[0-9]` gives

```
rc  libpython3.4:amd64                            3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3                           amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.4)
rc  libpython3.4-minimal:amd64                    3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3                           amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.4)
rc  libpython3.5-minimal:amd64                    3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.5)
ii  libpython3.6:amd64                            3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.6)
ii  libpython3.6-dev:amd64                        3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.6)
ii  libpython3.6-minimal:amd64                    3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)
ii  libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64                     3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.6)
rc  python3.4                                     3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3                           amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.4)
rc  python3.4-minimal                             3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3                           amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.4)
rc  python3.5-minimal                             3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.5)
ii  python3.6                                     3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.6)
ii  python3.6-dev                                 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.6)
ii  python3.6-minimal                             3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3                           amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)
```

And `apt-cache policy texlive-latex-base texlive-binaries`
gives

```
texlive-latex-base:
  Installiert:           2017.20180305-1
  Installationskandidat: 2017.20180305-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2017.20180305-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
texlive-binaries:
  Installiert:           2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1
  Installationskandidat: 2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2017.20170613.44572-8build1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

`pdftex -v` and `pdflatex -v` both give

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

Comment: Is your system a fresh install or an upgrade?

Comment: You do not modify or change default python or you break your system. It used to be reinstall was only option, now it may be repairable from a chroot using live install flash drive. But if you do not need the other versions, be sure to have good backups, just in case.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep python3.[0-9]` to the question. What is your real problem?

Comment: @ajgringo619 It is an upgrade from 16.04

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I now realize that I broke something: My pdflatex is not working anymore see #580255. What can I do now to repair it? (I did the modifying to get youtube-dl run again. But pdflatex is far more important to me).

Comment: @N0rbert I added this. But my real problem now ist that pdflatex isn't working anymore, see case #580255.

Comment: @oldfred Problem #580255 solved. I did not know that python2.7 is allowed to be installed parallel to python3.

Comment: What is "case #580255"? See updated answer. Also add output of `apt-cache policy texlive-latex-base texlive-binaries` and `pdftex -v` with `pdflatex -v` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert  This is case #580255 [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580255/] which is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have some leftovers from 16.04 LTS, then you have to remove its Python packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge libpython3.4:amd64 libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 python3.4 python3.4-minimal python3.5-minimal
```

Then remove packages which are ready for auto-remove:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

---

Your output is normal. On my Ubuntu MATE 18.04.5 LTS system I have:

> `python3: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz`

and it works normally.

So I have Python 3 installed from repositories. The python folders in `/usr/local` are created by `pip3`, so they are safe too.